# Как пишется "не к спеху"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Интересно, а как пишется "не к спеху"?

Answer (score 3):

Раздельно: "не к спеху", так что, Вы правильно написали. Не с отыменными наречиями пишется раздельно. "Не к добру", "не к спеху".